# PHP + HTML - Connecting to a Local MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection, localhost

I've been trying to connect to a local MySQL database and I don't think I even remotely know what I'm doing. I've done some googling and I was told to try these:

```
<?php

      $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "dbName") or die ("<p>Error connecting to the Database.</p>");

?>
```

and

```
<?php

      $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "dbName") or die ("<p>Error connecting to the Database.</p>");

?>
```

Both of these returned with text on the webpage saying `Error connecting to the Database.` meaning that clearly didn't work.

If anyone knows or can link me to a reliable method of doing this, that would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Edit: Yes, I'm very new to PHP but I'm familiar with JS/Node.JS so things seem a little familiar to me, that is, besides the MySQL stuff :P

Comment: 1. Is your database already running, and 2. Is the username, password, and database name called 'root', 'password', and 'dbName' respectively?

Comment: @RobbieW. yes and yes

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentaion](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php), if you try this at least if it doesnt work you will get some indication why

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "user", "password", "database", 3306);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: erm yeah im quite a beginner to PHP so I kinda go with the procedural way of coding with php...

Comment: Yeah, I just pointed out the error handling code for you, so you will get an actual error back which tells you why it didnt work instead of just echoing back a generic error message

Answer (score 0):

**Editted**

Try this 
It will help you in identifying exact problem.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "password", "dbName");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
exit();
}
```

Comment: 1. I simply used `password` as a replacement. Im not gonna share my password out to the internet... 2. yeah it has an actual db name and ive set that in the code

Answer (score 0):

By shell you can access with those credentials?
Like:
mysql -uroot -ppasswoord -hlocalhost dbName